# Visual basic membership program using select case?

Tags: vb.net, select

I am writing a program which asks the user for their age and the number of years they have been a member, I am trying to do this through using select case. However it doesn't appear to be working, all of the ages are fine but if I use the checkbox to say they are a veteran and should get a discount it doesn't work. Also the number of years they have been a member doesn't change the price/ category, my program is simple and I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Screen shot of program:http://gyazo.com/ebab66526068f4c81a30c624aada7f7c

Code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnCalc_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer

    x = Val(txtAge.Text)
    y = Val(txtYears.Text)


    Select Case x
        Case Is <= 18
            lblPrice.Text = ("£60")
            lblCategory.Text = ("Junior")
        Case 19 To 49
            lblPrice.Text = ("£120")
            lblCategory.Text = ("Senior")
        Case Is >= 50
            lblPrice.Text = ("£80")
            lblCategory.Text = ("Over 50")
        Case chkVeteran.Checked
            lblPrice.Text = ("£50")
        Case Is <= 18 And y >= 2
            lblPrice.Text = ("£40")
            lblCategory.Text = ("2 year junior discount")
        Case Is >= 50 And y >= 10
            lblPrice.Text = ("£90")
            lblCategory.Text = ("10 year senior discount")
        Case chkVeteran.Checked And y >= 10
            lblPrice.Text = ("£20")
            lblCategory.Text = ("10 year veteran discount")
    End Select


End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Define "it doesn't work."  What *does* it do?  When you step through this in a debugger, where does the observed behavior differ from the expected behavior?  What are the runtime values when that happens?

Comment: `Select Case x` specifies a selection of `x` which you then compare to the unrelated `Case chkVeteran.Checked`. I would put the value and string in variables then apply the checkbox logic after the case, then update the UI

Answer (score 2):

Only one `Case` block can run, but you seem to be expecting multiple blocks to run.  Consider this subset of your clauses:

```
Case Is <= 18
    lblPrice.Text = ("£60")
    lblCategory.Text = ("Junior")
Case chkVeteran.Checked
    lblPrice.Text = ("£50")
Case Is <= 18 And y >= 2
    lblPrice.Text = ("£40")
    lblCategory.Text = ("2 year junior discount")
```

If `x` is less than or equal to `18` then the *first* `Case` block will run.  The others will be ignored, regardless of the state of `chkVeteran` or `y`.  A series of `Case` clauses needs to be essentially mutually-exclusive in order for the logic to make sense.  For example:

```
Case Is <= 18 And y < 2
    lblPrice.Text = ("£60")
    lblCategory.Text = ("Junior")
Case Is <= 18 And y >= 2
    lblPrice.Text = ("£40")
    lblCategory.Text = ("2 year junior discount")
```

These two clauses are exclusive, so only one of them can apply at any time.  Each clause will be checked in order from first to last and the first one which matches will execute.  So you should set up your logic such that the *first* clause which matches should be the *only* clause which matches.

---

**Edit:** In response to a separate comment thread...

You defined the logic as:

> A sports club has three categories of membership charge. Juniors (ages up to 18) pay £60 per year, seniors (19-49) pay £120 and Veterans (50 and over) pay £80. Juniors who have been a member for 2 years or more get a £20 reduction. Seniors and Veterans who have been members for 10 years or more get a £30 reduction.

That sounds to me like 2 conditional sequences.  The first one would define the base rate, something like this:

```
If age < 19 Then
    rate = 60
Else If age < 50 Then
    rate = 120
Else
    rate = 80
End If
```

The second one would define a discount for the base rate, something like this:

```
If age < 19 And tenure > 1 Then
    rate = rate - 20
Else If age > 18 And tenure > 9 Then
    rate = rate - 30
End If
```

Two separate conditional sequences, each checking *exactly* the conditions explicitly defined in the requirements.  You can then further refactor them to make the semantic meaning more clear.  For example, extract the definitions of "Junior, Senior, and Veteran" into separate logic:

```
If IsJunior(age) Then
    rate = 60
Else If IsSenior(age) Then
    rate = 120
Else If IsVeteran(age) Then
    rate = 80
End If
```

You can create functions for each of those, like:

```
Function IsJunior(ByVal age As Integer) As Boolean
    Return age < 19
End Function
```

This extracts the details of the implementation into smaller helper functions and allows the top-level logic to be expressed in semantic concepts rather than implementation details, allowing the overall expression of logic to match the description given by the requirements much more clearly.

Comment: None of this makes sense so I decided to do it as an if statement.

Comment: If i use Elseif, why doesn't it work if i do 'Elseif x = 19 to 49"

Comment: @Finn: Define "doesn't work."  Is there an error?  What is the updated code and how does it behave when you debug it?

Comment: I'm just writing it now, I will post it up when I am done

Answer (score 0):

this is pretty tough using select case cuz u will not be able to pass both the values of x and y together when u are using codes like  Case Is <= 18 And y >= 2

better use if then else

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer

    x = Val(txtAge.Text)
    y = Val(txtYears.Text)


    If x <= 18 Then
        lblPrice.Text = ("£60")
        lblCategory.Text = ("Junior")
    ElseIf x >= 19 And x <= 49 Then
        lblPrice.Text = ("£120")
        lblCategory.Text = ("Senior")
    ElseIf x >= 50 And y < 10 Then
        lblPrice.Text = ("£80")
        lblCategory.Text = ("Over 50")
    ElseIf chkVeteran.Checked And y> Then
        lblPrice.Text = ("£50")
    ElseIf x <= 18 And y >= 2 Then
        lblPrice.Text = ("£40")
        lblCategory.Text = ("2 year junior discount")
    ElseIf x >= 50 And y >= 10 Then
        lblPrice.Text = ("£90")
        lblCategory.Text = ("10 year senior discount")
    ElseIf chkVeteran.Checked And y >= 10 Then
        lblPrice.Text = ("£20")
        lblCategory.Text = ("10 year veteran discount")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Some of the fields are empty")
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class